# UserCredential in Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm having an error with Firebase for the first time, and not sure why it keeps showing the error.
Error :

> The name 'UserCredential' is defined in the libraries 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart (via package:firebase/firebase.dart)' and 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'.\nTry using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // Create user object based on FirebaseUser
  CustomUsers _customModelForFirebaseUser(user) {
    return user != null ? CustomUsers(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth changed user stream
  Stream<CustomUsers> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_customModelForFirebaseUser);
  }

  //Signin Anon
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      CustomUsers user = userCredential.user;
      print(_customModelForFirebaseUser(user));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The package have same class name, which causing packing to conflicts. Try to hide one of them like this

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' hide UserCredential;
```

For more explanation check out this webiste [dart-flutter-how-to-solve-naming-conflict-or-ambiguous](https://coflutter.com/dart-flutter-how-to-solve-naming-conflict-or-ambiguous-import/)

Comment: Find the reason. Thank you I imported
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'; 
import 'import 'package:firebase.dart';
And they interfered.